# getting values from textbox using jquery [output via php variable]

Tags: php, jquery

main.php:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">     

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {                 
        alert("What will i put here!");
    });

</SCRIPT>      

<input type = "submit" id = "btnSubmit" value = "Try IT!" />

<div id = "show_search2">
</div>
```

output.php:

```
<?php $val = $_POST['btnSubmit'];
echo "<H1>$val</H1>"; ?>
```

What specific jQuery functionality can get the value of the `btnSubmit` and access it through `$_POST` and output it to the div `show_search2`? I used prototype.js but it provides conflict with my other JS scripts in the index.

Note: all my script source is included in index and that's why I didn't include the source in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var submitVal = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "url_of_your_output.php",
       data: {btnSubmit : submitVal},
       success: function(response) {
            $("#show_search2").html(response);  //response from output.php
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes something like that, can i actually $_POST the btnSubmit value or a textbox? can i change submitVal = $('txtUserName').val(); and submit it to the php script and dispplay the output as it is ?

Comment: yes of course, you could do submitVal = $('#txtUserName').val(); to get value of input field having id = txtUserName and pass it in

Comment: you could add a form wrapping the input and submit fields

Comment: i just did what you said but it didn't work. it is just redirected on my index page.